# No puedo añadir branches en la database de Firebase

Tags: firebase, realtime-database

No puedo añadir branches en la realtime-database de Firebase

```java
 String uid = user.getUid();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
            
            
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Logbook").push();
//Data will be saved in "Logbook" node.
Map<String, Object> updatemap = new HashMap<>();
updatemap.put("id", databaseReference.getKey());
updatemap.put("Uid", uid);
updatemap.put("picName", "");

databaseReference.setValue(updatemap);


databaseReference.setValue(updatemap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
      {
           @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
      {
// Values Updated
      }
     }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
         @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
   {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
  });
```

Aparentemente nada esta mal. Pero en el debug breakpoint llega a `onFailure` and says iny pone en el *progressDialog*:

[image: first_image]    [image: second_image]   [image: third_image]  [image: forth_image]

En las reglas de la database tengo todo a "true" así que cualquiera tiene permiso para write o read.

Comment: ¿Qué error está dando exactamente?

Comment: @A.Cedano no da ningún error, sólo no escribe nada en la database y ya está

Comment: ¿Revisaste bien? Primero estás haciendo un push y luego escribiendo o intentando escribir más cosas en esa nueva referencia que se habrá creado en el push. ¿Por qué lo haces así? ¿No sería mejor escribirlo todo de una vez? No entiendo mucho la pregunta, pues dices algo de `Failure` que no es claro, ¿podrías explicarlo? *"Pero en el debug breakpoint llega a onFailure and says iny pone en el progressDialog:"* ¿? Si llega ahí estará escribiendo el error en la pila, puesto que tienes esto: `e.printStackTrace();` ¿revisaste los errores de la pila?

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue eliminar el proyecto de firebase y crear otro nuevo. Cambiar el la id de la aplicacion ("com.example.example") a cualquier otro porque Firebase detecta que el anterior ya está siendo usado aunque lo borres. Pues crear un nuevo proyecto de firebase y copias todo ahí; la nueva id de la app y el SHA1 que seguiría siendo el mismo si no creas otro proyecto en android studio.
Este fallo me hizo perder decenas de horas cuando en realidad fue un fallo inexplicable de Google Firebase que no reaccionaba.